# How to pass a header as argument in curl command?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am attempting to do a curl command that uses a predefined variable as a header.

```
header='-H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "userGUID: 7feb6e62-35da-4def-88e9-376e788ffd97" -H "Content-Length: 51"'
```

And this is essentially the curl command

```
curl $header -w "http code: %{http_code}\\n" -X POST -d $BODY $URL
```

Which then returns the error message

```
rl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 7feb6e62-35da-4def-88e9-376e788ffd97"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 51"
```

This works as expected

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "userGUID: 7feb6e62-35da-4def-88e9-376e788ffd97" -H "Content-Length: 51" -w "http code: %{http_code}\\n" -X POST -d $BODY $URL
```

The reason I'm trying to pass the header as a variable is because I'm writing a script that loops through and array, but currently this does not work with headers for some reason. There is no issue passing arguments for body.

Comment: Word splitting makes your header arguments `-H`, `"Content-Type:`, `application/json"`, etc. I recommend that you use an array to save headers. Otherwise you probably need `eval`.

Comment: Would you do the eval command within the curl command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be aware that variable expansion in bash can catch people off guard easily.

A pretty good rule of thumb is to put double quotes around any variable you want to expand like `curl "$header" -w "http code: %{http_code}\\n" -X POST -d "$BODY" "$URL"`.

Bash always expands `$SOMETHING` variables if they appear on their own, or if they appear in double quotes. (Not if they appear in single quotes).

When expanded **with** double quotes they are treated as a single "token" by the shell, no matter what.

When expanded **without** double quotes they will be parsed as if you had typed their contents instead of the variable. So - if that variable had spaces, that may mean the shell will treat those as separators between arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up fixing it. Replaced double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `curl '$header' ...` gives me `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: $header`

Comment: @AlexS, eh? The double quotes are correct (ish; you can't pass multiple arguments that way; for that, an array is needed, as described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)); the single quotes are wrong (they pass strings with literal `$`s, not variable contents, to `curl`)..